# Java boolean in if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

When I run this code I have the value no as an output. I don't understand why boolean variable isNegative stays as true while x is initiated as 100. This on java. Thank for the future help.

```
boolean isNegative = (x < 0);
if (isNegative)
{
x = 100;
if (isNegative)
System.out.println("no");
else
System.out.println("yes");
}
else
System.out.println("maybe");
```

Comment: `When I run this code I have the value no as an output. I don't understand why boolean variable isNegative stays as true while x is initiated as 100. ` - **No, this is not correct. Your code will print `maybe`**.

Comment: Changing the value of `x` doesn't change the value of `isNegative`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No it doesn’t (assuming `x` was less than 0 initially).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - OP has not mentioned the value of `x` before `boolean isNegative = (x < 0);`. Assuming the default value of `x` as `0`, it will print `maybe`. You are righty though that it will print `no` assuming `x` was less than `0` initially.

Comment: In math you'd be right, but in Java `=` is (re)definition and not equality.

Answer (score 2):

because the value of `isNegative` is never changed, just update the value when you change `x`

```
boolean isNegative = (x < 0);
if (isNegative)
{
   x = 100;
   isNegative = (x < 0);
   if (isNegative)
      System.out.println("no");
   else
      System.out.println("yes");
}
else
    System.out.println("maybe");
```

Answer (score 0):

that because you boolean is initialized before your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Because (x < 0) is an expression evaluated at runtime just one time. This

```
boolean isNegative = (x < 0);
```

gets executed just one time. After that, isNegative will be always false (assuming x is already negative). If you later change 'x', then isNegative needs to be re-evaluated or re-calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably repeating what others have said, but perhaps I can add something.  The question shows a misunderstanding of program execution, which is pretty fundamental.

Execution proceeds through a sequence of statements. The sequence is modified by loops, method calls, and so on, but that's not really germane to this answer.

An assignment (to a variable) is a statement that computes a value, possibly using other values available right now. It is most definitely **not** the same thing as an equation, which states that two expressions mean the same thing.

So, in your case,

```
 isNegative = (x < 0);
```

looks at the value of `x` at the time the statement is encountered, computes the value of `x < 0` (which is either true or false), and assigns that value to 'isNegative`.  Then we proceed to the next statement.

If there is no subsequent assignment to `isNegative` then its value will not change. It has not somehow been yoked to the value of `x` in a way that `isNegative` will automatically reflect the current sign of `x`.

Aside: you could, if you wanted, define a useful method:

```
boolean isNegative(int val) {
   return val < 0;
}
```

and then use `isNegative(x)` when you wanted to test the current value of `x`.

For what it's worth, the concept of 'variable' in the sense of programming is a thing peculiar to programming, and there are many eminent computer scientists who'll say it's quite a deep idea.